# How to enable split keyboard for iPad in the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, ios-simulator

I'm trying to test the layout of an app and I want to change the keyboard settings in the iPad simulator so the keyboard splits. However, I don't see the option to change it anywhere in the keyboard settings.

[image: Settings menu in emulator]

Is this disabled in the simulator or is there another way to change the keyboard to split? I'm testing on an iPad Pro on iOS 11.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has decided (for whatever reason) that you can't split the keyboard on iPad Pro (unless you are using the Zoomed display mode). Switch to a smaller iPad simulator to get the split keyboard functionality.